# Can you hide obsolete or orphan changsets in TortoiseHG?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Having used `hg evolve` for a while TortoiseHG (version 5.6.1 on Windows) now shows a large number of obsolete changesets.

These show up red or gray, like this:

[image]

When you select one of these, THG will tell you:

> Obsolete state: orphan (red items)

or

> Obsolete state: obsolete (gray items)

For the most part I don't need to know about these anymore, and it would be nice to just remove them from the view (but not from the repository). Ideally I'd like the red & gray line items to just not be shown.

Looking in the THG settings and also THG documentation ([1](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=obsolete&check_keywords=yes&area=default), [2](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=obsolecense&check_keywords=yes&area=default#)) as well as web searches I haven't been able to find a way to do this. (The relevant actual [Mercurial docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html) don't mention THG at all).

**Is it possible to hide orphaned or obsolete changesets in THG?**

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the search toolbar, there is an icon to enable/disable hidden changesets.  Caveat: I'm currently running 5.0.2 so it may be different in 5.6.1 but it should still be there.

[image: image highlighting search button and relevant icon]

Comment: This is pretty close (maybe as closed as THG gets right now)... but I find with that option ON (ie., telling it to hide them) *orphan* changesets are still shown; and if their predecessor was obsolete, it is shown also, including the entire chain of obsoletes.   So its only hiding 1+ obsolete changeset(s) which never lead to an orphan.  The example in the question's screenshot is therefore not hidden.

Comment: In fairness to your answer, I realized I did not ask if I can hide "orphan or obsolete" changesets even though that is what I had in mind, the question originaly only asked about obsolete (edited since).

Comment: @StayOnTarget Orphans are supposed to be dealt with.  If you evolve or prune them, they will become obsolete and can be hidden.